# neo4j Cypher -- traverse variable length path, but stop when a label is found

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose my graph database has a 'flow' of `foo` nodes. in between  each `foo` nodes might be *any* number of `bar`, `bar1`, `bar2`, ...`barN` nodes which ultimately connect to the next `foo` node.

So, all of these are possible

- (a:foo)-->(:bar)-->(b:foo)
- (b:foo)-->(:bar)-->(c:foo)-->(:bar1)-->(d:foo)
- (a:foo)-->(:bar)-->(:bar1)-->(:bar2)-->(:barN)-->(c:foo)

etc.

**I'd like to return each distinct pair of `foo` nodes which do NOT have any other `foo` nodes between them**

For the above examples, the solution should return:

- a, b
- b, c
- c, d
- a, c

Solution should NOT include the following, which have foo nodes between them:

- b, d
- a, d

---

What I've tried. this returns all foo pairs that connect, regardless of what's in between.

```
MATCH x=(a:foo)-[:RELTYPE*1..]->(b:foo)
RETURN a,b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH x = (a:foo)-[:RELTYPE*..]->(b:foo)
WHERE NONE(n IN NODES(x)[1..-1] WHERE ANY(l IN LABELS(n) WHERE l = 'foo'))
RETURN a, b
```

[UPDATE]

Or even better:

```
MATCH x = (a:foo)-[:RELTYPE*..]->(b:foo)
WHERE NONE(n IN NODES(x)[1..-1] WHERE n:foo)
RETURN a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage APOC Procedures for [path expansion procs](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/path-finding/path-expander/) which can handle this kind of use case.

Using this graph:

```
CREATE (a:foo {name:'a'}), (b:foo {name:'b'}), (c:foo {name:'c'}), (d:foo {name:'d'}), 
(a)-[:RELTYPE]->(:bar)-[:RELTYPE]->(b), 
(b)-[:RELTYPE]->(:bar)-[:RELTYPE]->(c)-[:RELTYPE]->(:bar1)-[:RELTYPE]->(d), 
(a)-[:RELTYPE]->(:bar)-[:RELTYPE]->(:bar1)-[:RELTYPE]->(:bar2)-[:RELTYPE]->(:barN)-[:RELTYPE]->(c)
```

We can apply this query:

```
MATCH (start:foo)
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(start, {relationshipFilter:'RELTYPE>', labelFilter:'/foo'}) YIELD node as end
RETURN start, end
```

This starts at every :foo node, traverses only outgoing :RELTYPE relationships, and will terminate expansion when reaching a :foo labeled node (the `/` before the 'foo' in the label filter indicates that this is a termination filter on the label).